# iTunes Sandbox account credentials are asked continuously

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am trying to implement IAP in my application but now it asks for sandbox account continuously. I tried removing that account from sandbox testers, but result is same.I removed all IAP related codes,but result is still same.I downloaded my app from store(that has no IAP implementation), even it still asks for credentials. I am going crazy with it.
I also tried hard reboot and removing transactions in all cases but it does not help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I can find that incrementing application version. Once I change the version app to v1.1 from v1.0, this annoying credential screen disappear. I am quite glad now

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sandbox account from your iPhones settings and if logged into game centre with that account, remove it from there as well.

Comment: I logged out so far. I did not log for game center

Comment: Is it still asking you to sign in all of the time after logging out?

Comment: Yes. It asks always. There are some other threads like my problem. Hope it clarifies